# Is NULL not allowed is SQL delete statement (for Derby)?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis, derby

Does anyone know why the following query fails in Derby?

```
delete from MyTable
where
((null = null) or (col1 = null)) OR
((102 = null) or (col2 = 102)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "null" at line 3, column 3.
SQLState:  42X01
ErrorCode: -1
```

The sql is being generated in a java program based on SQL I've written into an iBatis ORM layer config. The prepared statement is as follows:

```
delete from MyTable
where
((? = null) or (col1 = ?)) OR
((? = null) or (col2 = ?)))
```

As you can see what I'm trying to say is that if the *parameter* is not null then test the column value against the parameter

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I should have added the sql is being generated in a java program by an iBatis orm layer. The prepared statement is as follows delete from MyTable where ((? = null) or (col1 = ?)) OR ((? = null) or (col2 = ?))) As you can see what I'm trying to say is that if the parameter is not null then test the column value against the parameter. I've edited the original question to clarify this (*hopefully*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
DELETE FROM `name_of_table` WHERE `name_of_column` IS NULL
```

SQL has this really weird property where you can use `=value` with most values, except NULL.

Comment: Nothing weird. NULL != NULL is core part of trinary logic. If soething is not known (NULL) it is not identical to some other not known value.

Comment: @TomTom, what is weird is that SQL uses "IS" instead of "=" only for the value of NULL.

Comment: Actually no. tIt is the logical conclusion of trinary logic.

Comment: @TomTom, it is neither logical nor illogical... it is all a matter of the meaning that we choose to assign to syntax. In my own opinion, it is weird that SQL special cases NULL in this way, because the intended meaning of such a statement is obvious and unambiguous, and most other languages with a notion of null do not require a special syntax for determining if something is null.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, any operator where one of the arguments is `NULL` evaluates to `NULL`. So `1 + NULL` is `NULL`, `MAX(NULL)` is `NULL`, and so on. Most importantly, in your case, `X = NULL` *always* evaluates to `NULL`, even if X is `NULL` itself (that is, `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `NULL` not `true`).

The exact error you get is that the keyword `NULL` is not actually valid on the left-hand side of a comparison. But even if you fixed that, you'd still find that none of your rows ever match. As others have said, the correct comparison to use when trying to determine whether something is null is `IS NULL`, as in `X IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the where clause suggests it should match *every* row (if you expect `null = null` to be true, which it generally wouldn't be in SQL) - do you really want to delete the whole table's contents? Likewise `102 = null` is a pretty bizarre kind of comparison, unless you've somehow got a column called 102 (which I'd at least *hope* is prohibited).

What are you trying to actually match? As others have said, you should use "is null" to compare a value against null - but it sounds like your query has rather bigger problems. If you could tell us what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you write the query better.

Comment: The query is a parameterised query and what I'm trying to say is if the *parameter* is null then ignore the condition. I've edited the question to clarify this *hopefully*.

Comment: @leftbrainlogic: Are the first and third parameters meant to be column names or values? If they're values, you can check for nullity yourself and adjust the query accordingly rather than passing the data to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you seem not to have gotten a good answer yet? I have a similar problem with Derby's handling of `NULL` values:

[Derby's handling of NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905826/derbys-handling-of-null-values)

The fact is that Derby needs a type associated with NULL. What you would have to do if you wrote the SQL yourself is to `cast(null to int)` or something like that. Unfortunately, as you mentioned it, the SQL is generated by iBATIS, so maybe an upgrade might work? Did iBATIS create a fix for this, in the mean time?

Otherwise, this may help you:

http://anydoby.com/jblog/en/java/143