# How to return a NULL value for Date type column in SQL in Derby?

Tags: sql, derby

In my Sql, I want to group by some columns having some conditions , so for other column, they are date type. I just want to manually return null  for them, But i don't know how. 
Can you give me some advice how to return null for date type column? To simply use NULL doesn't work in Apache Derby which is odd.

I am also interested in the answer for other database. If you can also answer it, it will be great.

**EDIT**

Reply to comment, I want 
`select NULL from TABLE`, and NULL stands for an empty value of DATE type column. I just want to return a NULL value manually.But it throws exception tells me NULL is invalid. Is that possible?

**EDIT**

I found an workaround to return a constant value for date type in Derby. That is using `Date(789)` which is date function in derby. But I am still insterested in how to return an empty constant value for Date?

**EDIT**

`NULL` in query in Derby must be casted to correct type. which is a bit different.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do - maybe show us your code and any attempts you've made.

Comment: Do you get me I want to know how to return a constant empty value for DATE like '' for VARCHARS?

Comment: Apologies, what you're trying to do is so simple in most RDBMS that I assumed that I had misunderstood you. Obviously, the "simple" way isn't working for you...

Comment: That is right. Maybe other RDBMS all support NULL.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905826/derbys-handling-of-null-values

Comment: Please show us the **full** SQL that you are running that produces the error message. Derby certainly supports NULL for DATE columns

Comment: @ypercube, It works like a charm. it should use cast(null as DATE). ypercube 's link is very helpful!!! Thanks to ypercube

Comment: Then please remember to post all relevant information (e.g. SQL statements) the next time you post a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use `cast(null as DATE) AS START_DATE` expression. As in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905826/derbys-handling-of-null-values).

I just add here for others to find it out easily. One thing interesting is even the column `START_DATE` is `NOT NULL`, I can still fake a `NULL` return value for this column. Actually it should be , not a surprise at all here,right?

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is NULL-able you should declare the property also as DateTime nullable: `DateTime? MyDate;`

Comment: you are right. But the problem is using NULL makes the SQL parse error in Derby. Encounter the 'NULL' looks like in derby. it's not allowed to use NULL keyword.

Comment: ah - I see your problem. well then you need to check if (!MyDate.HasValue) write Date(789) to database

Comment: actually it's nothing to do with insert. But query with some constant data or say fake data, I used cast(null as DATE) to return a NULL value in query .